# Synonym to point two tables with same name but different suffix?

Tags: oracle, synonym

I am pretty new to oracle and trying to create a synonym to point two different tables on different days. Please see my example below.

I have two tables named `table_1` and `table _2` and a synonym `table`. At first i point the synonym to table_1;

`CREATE SYNONYM table for schema.table_1;`

Next day i would want to point the synonym to `table_2`. Should i use another statement like

`CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM table for schema.table_2;`

or is there any other way. Could someone help me?

Comment: no i am just giving an example table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous options.

1. Create a database job which will do synonym update by schedule. It may cause troubles for queries which are using the synonym at the time of its replacement.
2. Create a package with procedures which will hide table switching from application layer.
3. Create a view to hide table switching based on example select below. Assuming that you are only reading and tables have the same structure.
4. Don't duplicate tables.

Select for view

```
SELECT DUMMY
FROM (
  SELECT 'X' AS DUMMY, 0 AS SEP FROM DUAL TABLE1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y' AS DUMMY, 1 AS SEP FROM DUAL TABLE2)
WHERE
  SEP = MOD(EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE), 2)
```

Comment: I need clarification regarding the synonyms. Should i replace synonym everyday?

Comment: Arun, you have not explained why you are doing all of this, what is your high level goal and problem. Why you want to make synonym? Are you rotating tables every day? If yes - why?

Comment: We truncate and load the tables daily so we are trying to create two set of tables with same name but different suffixes and point synonym to those tables in alternative days.

Comment: Arun, why you need to alternate two tables? What's wrong with using just one?

Comment: Cause we have user sessions open while we are trying to truncate the tables.